# How do I define the behaviour of functions `match` and `%in%` for a defined S4 class in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

I have created a package with several R classes that map integers to various structures that often come up in combinatorics and vice versa. Although the classes only encapsulate *mappings* (the number of structures grows very quickly, easily reaching trillions) rather than actually storing the structures, it is convenient to think of instances of the classes as vectors "containing" the structures, and it would be nice for the instances to behave like vectors.

For example, one of the classes is `PPV` (for permutations pseudo vector), set up as:

```
setClass(
  Class = "PPV",
  representation(k = "numeric", items = "vector")
)
```

In order to make it behave somewhat like a vector, I have added definitions for `length` and `[`:

```
setMethod(
  f = "length",
  signature = "PPV",
  definition = function(x) # blah blah blah
)

setMethod(
  f = "[",
  signature = "PPV",
  definition = function(x, i, j, drop) {
    # blah blah blah
  }
)
```

So far, so good. This allows me to use `length` on instances and access structures "contained" in instances by indexing:

```
> # (ppv is a constructor)
> # Create a pseudo-vector of 3-permutations of the first 5 letters.
> ps <- ppv(3, letters[1:5])
> # Like vectors, access we can access structures "contained" by index.
> for (i in 1:5) cat(ps[i],"\n")
a b c 
a c b 
c a b 
c b a 
b c a 
> # Like vectors, function length is meaningful.
> length(ps)
[1] 60
```

I also have mappings from the structures to the index and tests for existence defined, and it seems that it would be most exoteric for these mappings to be implemented via the `match` and `%in%` functions respectively. This is what I have so far:

```
setMethod(
  f = "%in%",
  signature = c("vector", "PPV"),
  definition = function(x, table)
    # blah blah blah
)

setMethod(
  f = "match",
  signature = c("vector", "PPV"),
  definition = function(x, table) {
    # blah blah blah
  }
)
```

The problem is that when I install and load the library, these don't appear to be defined:

```
> some.permutation <- c("a", "c", "e")
> some.permutation %in% ps
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
> match(some.permutation, ps)
Error in match(some.permutation, ps) : 'match' requires vector arguments
```

Yet, when I explicitly execute the code contained in the files, it works:

```
> some.permutation %in% ps
[1] TRUE
> match(some.permutation, ps)
[1] 25
> ps[25]
[1] "a" "c" "e"
```

Why is it that the definitions for `length` and `[` are being executed when the package is loaded but those for `%in%` and `match`, in the same file and with the same settings, are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match()` is not a generic (`isGeneric("match")`), so you'd like to make it one, maybe a bit more sensibly than dispatching on all arguments.

```
setGeneric("match", signature=c("x", "table"))
```

Write the method to follow the signature

```
setMethod("match", c("vector", "PPV"),
    function(x, table, nomatch = NA_integer_, incomparables = NULL)
{
    "match,vector,PPV-method"
})
```

Remember in your package NAMESPACE to export the class and generic

```
exportClasses("PPV")
export("match")
```

For `%in%`, the implicit generic (created by defining a method without first using `setGeneric()`) is sensible, so just define the method

```
setMethod("%in%", c("vector", "PPV"), function(x, table) {
    message("%in%")
    match(x, table, nomatch=0L) > 0
})
```

Remember to export the implicit generic, too (`export("%in%")` in the NAMESPACE).

One might have hoped that since `base::%in%` is defined in terms of `match()`, and `match()` has been implemented for your class, it would not be necessary to implement a method for `%in%`. This is not the case, I think because `match()` is implemented in C in a way that does not first look for a generic.